# Video.js - How to reference multiple videos in one page?

Tags: arrays, html5-video, video.js

My goodness, I cannot find an answer for this and I spent several hours already. 
**How can you reference multiple videos at the same time in video.js?**

The API documentation says:

> Referencing the Player: You just need to make sure your video tag has an ID. The example embed code has an ID of "example_video_1". If you have multiple videos on one page, make sure every video tag has a unique ID.
>
> var myPlayer = *V*("example_video_1");

This example shows a single ID, but it doesnt show how I can reference multiple IDs at the same time.

If I have 3 different tags: "video_1", "video_2", "video_3", how do I reference them all?

I tried an array and it didnt work. I also tried listing the videos like this:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("video_1", "video_2");
```

and didnt work neither.

Can somebody help me here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass multiple ids to `_V_()`. Either do them one at a time:

```
var myPlayer1 = _V_("video_1");
var myPlayer2 = _V_("video_2");
var myPlayer3 = _V_("video_3");
```

Or if you want them as an array:

```
var myPlayers = Array(_V_("video_1"), _V_("video_2"), _V_("video_3"));
myPlayers[1].play();
```

**Note:** this was written for an older version of video.js. `_V_()` still works but is deprecated: use `videojs()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
var video = [];
video[1] = _V_("Video1");
video[2] = _V_("Video2");
video[3] = _V_("Video3");
video[4] = _V_("Video4");
video[5] = _V_("Video5");
video[6] = _V_("Video6");
video[7] = _V_("Video7");
video[8] = _V_("Video8");
video[9] = _V_("Video9");
video[10] = _V_("Video10");
```